# pyelftools relocation section symbols

Tags: binary-analysis, static-analysis, python

I have been trying to get into reverse engineering as of late and after playing with Radare2 I realized I was playing with a lot of things without really understanding what I was doing. In an effort to rectify this I decided to do something a little more hands on and do some simple reversing exercises with python. I started by following this somewhat dated post.

```
https://anee.me/reversing-an-elf-from-the-ground-up-4fe1ec31db4a
```

I was attempting to look up symbols in the relocation section and it seems that one section provides accurate addresses but another does not and i'm at a bit of a loss as to why.

**My Code:**

```
import sys
from elftools.elf.elffile import ELFFile
from elftools.elf.relocation import RelocationSection
from elftools.elf.descriptions import describe_reloc_type


def process_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        e = ELFFile(f)
        for section in e.iter_sections():
            if not isinstance(section, RelocationSection):
                continue
            print(f'\n{section.name} with {section.num_relocations()} Sections: ')
            symbol_table = e.get_section(section['sh_link'])
            for relocation in section.iter_relocations():
                symbol = symbol_table.get_symbol(relocation['r_info_sym'])
                addr = hex(relocation['r_offset'])
                type = describe_reloc_type(relocation['r_info_type'], e)
                print(f'{addr}\t{type}\t{symbol.name}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        process_file(sys.argv[1])
```

**Returns:**

```
.rela.dyn with 9 Sections: 
0x3de8  R_X86_64_RELATIVE   
0x3df0  R_X86_64_RELATIVE   
0x4048  R_X86_64_RELATIVE   
0x3fd8  R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT   _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0x3fe0  R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT   __libc_start_main
0x3fe8  R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT   __gmon_start__
0x3ff0  R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT   _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0x3ff8  R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT   __cxa_finalize
0x4050  R_X86_64_COPY       stdin

.rela.plt with 5 Sections: 
0x4018  R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  puts
0x4020  R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  printf
0x4028  R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  fgets
0x4030  R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  strcmp
0x4038  R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  malloc
```

All of the addresses under '.rela.plt' have addresses that do not match the calls I know are being made to them.

For Example:

```
--cut--
0x11f0: mov eax, 0
0x11f5: call    0x1040 <<-- This is a call to printf
0x11fa: mov rdx, qword ptr [rip + 0x2e4f]       ** RIP + Offset: 0x4050  - calls: stdin
0x1201: mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
0x1205: mov esi, 0xa
0x120a: mov rdi, rax
0x120d: call    0x1050 <<-- This is a call to fgets
0x1212: mov rdx, qword ptr [rbp - 0x10]
--cut--
```

I have verified this with Radare2, and the correct addresses seem to be as follows.

```
 0x1030     sym.imp.puts                             
 0x1040     sym.imp.printf
 0x1050     sym.imp.fgets
 0x1060     sym.imp.strcmp
 0x1070     sym.imp.malloc
```

From what little I can find this may be due to dynamic linking but i'm not sure. I have been unable to find a way to get my script to output this section with what I believe are the appropriate addresses. Any information on how this process works, or how to retrieve the needed addresses with pyelftools would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question, though? Typically such a thing ends with a question mark and requests particular information or similar ...

Answer (score 2):

The `R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT` relocations are applied to the GOT (global offset table) slots, *not* to the call instructions you're seeing.

The call instructions go to the PLT (Program linkage table) stubs in the .plt section, and those, in turn, use the GOT and the `.rela.plt` relocations to resolve and jump to the final symbol in the external shared object. This process happens with the help of the dynamic linker (`ld.so`) and is a little too complicated to explain in this answer box, but you can find more information by searching for these terms.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that gives me a good place to start. I tried give you an up-vote but apparently my account, being new, does not have enough rep to do so.